# Redirect user from within AuthorizationHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm looking to execute some custom logic within an `AuthorizationHandler` that ultimately redirects a user if the logic calls for it, as shown below. Everything except the redirect executes properly. Is there a better/different way to do this with .NET 6?

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicyName", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new SomeRequirement()));
    });
```

`SomeAuthorizationHandler.cs`

```
public class SomeAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SomeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        SomeRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            // Execute custom logic
            if (true) {
                // DOES NOT WORK: Redirect user 
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/some-path");
            }
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The `SomeAuthorizationHandler` fires as expected and the `Redirect()` line will hit a breakpoint if set, but the user is never redirected to `/some-path`. Is there another/better way to redirect a user at this stage?

Comment: That’s not how the system works. Generally authorization handlers are a yes no decision, what happens with the request happens outside of them. I believe by default it will go through the forbid API on the authentication handler. There’s also an extensibility point in .NET 6 to determine how to handle authZ failures

Comment: You could use the `AuthorizationFilterContext` to get the context then you can redirect using `RedirectToActionResult` where you would like to redirect like this way `httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/AccessDenied", permanent: true);`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I don't believe that approach will work in .NET 6, as the `AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource` property is set to the current `HttpContext` which is shown in the sample code above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566024/202783

Comment: @davidfowl - understood. Would you mind providing some other resources for me to take a look at? I've tried searching for some of the things you've suggested but I'm coming up short. TIA

Comment: If you're using cookie authentication then it already has a way to configure the access denied path (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.accessdeniedpath?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

If you want to change what more control over all authorization result behavior then you can customize it via an IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the system works. Generally authorization handlers are a yes no decision, what happens with the request happens outside of them. I believe by default it will go through the forbid API on the authentication handler.

If you're using cookie authentication then it already has a way to configure the access denied path (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.accessdeniedpath?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

If you need even more control, there's an extensibility point in .NET 6 that lets determine to handle authZ failures. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0